# Modern OpenGL + SDL2 Triangle not showing up

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl-2

I am currently trying to learn how to use OpenGL in C++ after spending some time with just SDL2 and am struggling in getting my triangle to display on screen. I have been following a series of tutorials and trying to get a deep understanding of how everything works. I was successful in getting a simple solid colored triangle to show up on screen but when I try to give every vertex a different color nothing shows up except for the background.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/GLU.h>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_opengl.h>

//***************************************************************************
// The Width of the screen
//***************************************************************************
const GLuint SCREEN_WIDTH = 800;

//***************************************************************************
// The height of the screen
//***************************************************************************
const GLuint SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600;

bool success = GL_TRUE;

const GLchar* vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;\n"
"layout (location = 1) in vec3 color;\n"
"out vec3 ourColor;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);\n"
"ourColor = color;\n"
"}\0";

const GLchar* fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"in vec3 ourColor;\n"
"out vec4 color;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"color = vec4(ourColor, 1.0f);\n"
"}\n\0";

bool quit;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //***********************************************************************
    // Initialize SDL
    //***********************************************************************
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "SDL could not initialize!SDL Error :" <<
            std::string(SDL_GetError());

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else
    {
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 3);
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK,
            SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);

        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_STENCIL_SIZE, 8);
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);

        //*******************************************************************
        //The window we'll be rendering to
        //*******************************************************************
        SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("Triangle",
            SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SCREEN_WIDTH,
            SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN |
            SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);

        if (window == NULL)
        {
            std::cout << "Window could not be created!SDL_Error: " <<
                std::string(SDL_GetError()) << std::endl;

            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        //*******************************************************************
        //OpenGL context
        //*******************************************************************
        SDL_GLContext context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);

        //*******************************************************************
        // Set the required callback functions
        //*******************************************************************
        SDL_Event windowEvent;

        //*******************************************************************
        //Use OpenGL 3.3
        //*******************************************************************

        //*******************************************************************
        // Set this to true so GLEW knows to use a modern approach to 
        // retrieving function pointers and extensions
        //*******************************************************************
        glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

        //*******************************************************************
        // Initialize GLEW to setup the OpenGL Function pointers
        //*******************************************************************
        GLenum glewError = glewInit();
        if (GLEW_OK != glewError)
        {
            std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLEW: " << 
                glewGetErrorString(glewError) << std::endl;

            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);


        //*******************************************************************
        // Build and compile our shader program
        // Vertex shader
        //*******************************************************************
        GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
        glCompileShader(vertexShader);

        //*******************************************************************
        // Check for compile time errors
        //*******************************************************************
        GLint success;
        GLchar infoLog[512];
        glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
        if (!success)
        {
            glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
            std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED: " << 
                infoLog << std::endl;
        }

        //*******************************************************************
        // Fragment shader
        //*******************************************************************
        GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
        glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

        //*******************************************************************
        // Check for compile time errors
        //*******************************************************************
        glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
        if (!success)
        {
            glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
            std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED: " << 
                infoLog << std::endl;
        }

        //*******************************************************************
        // Link shaders
        //*******************************************************************
        GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
        glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
        glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

        //*******************************************************************
        // Check for linking errors
        //*******************************************************************
        glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
        if (!success) {
            glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 512, NULL, infoLog);
            std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED: " << infoLog << std::endl;
        }
        glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
        glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

        //*******************************************************************
        // Set up vertex data (and buffer(s)) and attribute pointers
        //*******************************************************************
        GLfloat vertices[] = {
            // Positions            // Colors
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,      1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  // Bottom Right
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,     0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,  // Bottom Left
            0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f,       0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f // Top
        };

        GLfloat colors[] = {
            1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f
        };

        GLuint VBO, VAO;
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
        glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);

        //*******************************************************************
        // Bind the Vertex Array Object first, then bind and set vertex 
        // buffer(s) and attribute pointer(s).
        //*******************************************************************
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        // Position attribute
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid *)0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        // Color attribute
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid *)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

        //*******************************************************************
        // Note that this is allowed, the call to glVertexAttribPointer 
        // registered VBO as the currently bound vertex buffer object so 
        // afterwards we can safely unbind
        //*******************************************************************
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        //*******************************************************************
        // Unbind VAO (it's always a good thing to unbind any buffer/array to
        // prevent strange bugs)
        //*******************************************************************
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        //*******************************************************************
        // DeltaTime variables
        //*******************************************************************
        GLdouble deltaTime = 0.0f;
        Uint64 lastFrame = 0L;
        Uint64 currentFrame = SDL_GetPerformanceCounter();

        quit = false;

        while (!quit)
        {
            //***************************************************************
            // Calculate delta time
            //***************************************************************
            lastFrame = currentFrame;
            currentFrame = SDL_GetPerformanceCounter();

            deltaTime = ((currentFrame - lastFrame) * 1000 /
                (GLdouble)SDL_GetPerformanceFrequency());

            double tmpDeltaTime = deltaTime;

            //std::cout << "Hello 1 - deltaTime: " << std::to_string(deltaTime) <<
            //    std::endl;

            if (SDL_PollEvent(&windowEvent))
            {
                if (windowEvent.type == SDL_QUIT)
                {
                    quit = true;
                }
            }

            //***************************************************************
            // Clear the colorbuffer and render
            //***************************************************************
            glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            //***************************************************************
            // Draw our first triangle
            //***************************************************************
            glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
            glBindVertexArray(VAO);
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
            glBindVertexArray(0);

            //***************************************************************
            // draw OpenGL: Swap the screen buffers
            //***************************************************************
            SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
        }

        //***************************************************************
        // Properly de-allocate all resources once they've outlived their 
        // purpose
        //***************************************************************
        glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
        glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);

        SDL_GL_DeleteContext(context);
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
        SDL_Quit();
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

As you can tell I am trying to use both OpenGL and SDL2 in the same project. The console shows me no errors when I run this code and I get my greenish background but no triangle at all. I have rewatched several "how shaders work" videos to see if I missed anything but cannot seem to find the source of my problem. What did I miss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program is a valid GL program which should not generate any errors. It correctly draws the background color, and correctly does not draw any triangle.

The default front face orientation in the GL is counter-clockwise (`GL_CCW`). The triangle which you define is oriented clockwise in clip space (and all following spaces NDC and window space). As a result,

```
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
```

will have the effect of culling the triangle before rasterization. To see the triangle, either disable (just don't enable it, it is off by default) `GL_CULL_FACE`, OR set the front-face convention to clockwise via `glFrontFace(GL_CW)`, OR just set `glCullFace(GL_FRONT)` to let the GL cull the front faces instead, OR just swap any two vertices in your array.

Comment: Thank you, this solved the issue and led me to learning something!